# ASP.NET MVC Url Rewrite - WWW redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I'm trying to add a iis url rewrite rule in web.config. The rule should be as follows.

If the url does not contain www, then redirect to www
However, if the Host contains, 'svha-prd-as-careservices-01' then do not redirect to www

Below is my code, the www redirect is working however, negate condition to check 'svha-prd-as-careservices-01' is not working. What am I missing?

```
<rule name="Redirect Non-WWW to WWW" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)svha-prd-as-careservices-01(.*)" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the second condition in your rule:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_HOST}" pattern="^(.*)svha-prd-as-careservices-01(.*)" negate="true" />
```

You probably mistakenly wrote {REQUEST_HOST} instead of {REQUEST_URI}.

Please modify it to the correct conditions and try again:

```
<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)svha-prd-as-careservices-01(.*)" negate="true" />
```